# The measured mcycle is less than minstret in Spike

Tags: riscv

I use spike to run the test program in "riscv-tools/riscv-tests/build/benchmarks":

```
$ spike multiply.riscv
```

And the output shows:

```
mcycle = 24096
minstret = 24103
```

Why `mcycle` is less than `minstret`?

Dose it means that spike can run more than one instructions in one cycle?
(I tried to trace spike code but cannot find how mcycle is counted.)

Comment: This is normal, benchmark just reads mcycles and minstret not in single instruction and not in adjacent ones, there is small amount of supporting code between readings, around 6-7 instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing of mcycle and minstret values are not from Spike in this case, it is from the test (benchmark). There is the code:

https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-benchmarks/blob/master/common/syscalls.c

```
#define NUM_COUNTERS 2
static uintptr_t counters[NUM_COUNTERS];
static char* counter_names[NUM_COUNTERS];

static int handle_stats(int enable)
{
  int i = 0;
#define READ_CTR(name) do { \
    while (i >= NUM_COUNTERS) ; \
    uintptr_t csr = read_csr(name); \
    if (!enable) { csr -= counters[i]; counter_names[i] = #name; } \
    counters[i++] = csr; \
  } while (0)

  READ_CTR(mcycle);
  READ_CTR(minstret);

#undef READ_CTR
  return 0;
}
```

There is some code between reading mcycle & minstret. And now you know how much code is there between readings.

In Spike mcycle & minstret are always equal by definition (they are handled by the same code): https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/9e012462f53113dc9ed00d7fbb89aeafeb9b89e9/riscv/processor.cc#L347

```
    case CSR_MINSTRET:
    case CSR_MCYCLE:
      if (xlen == 32)
        state.minstret = (state.minstret >> 32 << 32) | (val & 0xffffffffU);
      else
        state.minstret = val;
      break;
```

The syscalls.c was linked into multiply.riscv binary from https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-benchmarks/blob/master/multiply/bmark.mk - multiply_riscv_bin = multiply.riscv
$(multiply_riscv_bin):  ...  $(patsubst %.c, %.o,  ... syscalls.c  ... )

There is `_init` in syscalls.c function which calls `main` of the test and prints values, recorded on SYS_stats "syscall" with `handle_stats`.

```
void _init(int cid, int nc)
{
  init_tls();
  thread_entry(cid, nc);

  // only single-threaded programs should ever get here.
  int ret = main(0, 0);

  char buf[NUM_COUNTERS * 32] __attribute__((aligned(64)));
  char* pbuf = buf;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++)
    if (counters[i])
      pbuf += sprintf(pbuf, "%s = %d\n", counter_names[i], counters[i]);
  if (pbuf != buf)
    printstr(buf);

  exit(ret);
}
```